# Cassandra CQL shell does not show any output

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra on Windows 7. I create a keyspace k1 and a table Person in that keyspace.
But when I try to view the table I cannot see any ouput in the cql shell.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Victor, close each statement with a semicolon. The ellipses are showing that your statement is still open.